# Protractor: How I can stretching and replasing elements?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mouse, protractor, emulation

I have form like this:
[image]

And I want emulate to colums stretching. Also I can change the column headings places. So I want to emulate it to. I think I should use webdrivers methods. But I can't understand what kind of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a good use case for [`dragAndDrop()` browser action](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/6ebc4c3f8b557a56e53e0a1622d1b44b59f5bc04/spec/basic/actions_spec.js):

```
browser.actions().
    dragAndDrop(elm, {x: 400, y: 20}).
    perform();
```

You can also drag and drop from element to element:

```
browser.actions().
    dragAndDrop(elm, targetElm).
    perform();
```

And, FYI, here is the specification:

```
/**
 * Convenience function for performing a "drag and drop" manuever. The target
 * element may be moved to the location of another element, or by an offset (in
 * pixels).
 * @param {!webdriver.WebElement} element The element to drag.
 * @param {(!webdriver.WebElement|{x: number, y: number})} location The
 *     location to drag to, either as another WebElement or an offset in pixels.
 * @return {!webdriver.ActionSequence} A self reference.
 */
webdriver.ActionSequence.prototype.dragAndDrop = function(element, location) {
  return this.mouseDown(element).mouseMove(location).mouseUp();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to make an interesting note. I have the view:

```
<div class="n-grid-col-resize ng-scope" ng-if="column.resizable" ng-dblclick="menuOptions.onColumnAutoSize(column)" jQuery111202531640218477999="237"/>
```

In the picture it is vertical line that I should click and move. For a long time I couldn't understand why method dragAndDrop(), doubleClick() and so on isn't working with it. Answer is simple. I should get a centre of object. So, instead of:

```
browser.actions().doubleClick(my_elem).perform();
```

I should write:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove({x: x1, y: x2}).doubleClick().perform();
```

where

```
 var x1 = my_elem_x + my_elem_width/2;                
 var x2 = my_elem_y + my_elem_height/2;
```